# Aperture crop tool stopped working

Tags: aperture

I just got back from a hike, slurped the pix off my camera to my Mac, and can no longer crop my pix:

The usual shortcut <kbd>C</kbd> leaves the cursor as an arrow, not the crossed carpenter's squares.

If I add a crop brick to the adjustments pane, entering numbers there makes no difference.

I can make other adjustments -- e.g. levels -- so it's not like I've got it in quick preview mode.

- Mac Pro 2012 24 GB
- macOX Yosemite 10.10.5
- Aperture 3.6

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall of aperture (actually, copied the app from another computer) fixed the problem.

This is a windows-esque heavy handed solution that lacks elegance.